# Law of excluded middle for a statement "Formula A is provable"

Tags: logic

Often in many metamathematical proofs, I see the statement "Either the given formula $A$ is provable in this formal system or it is not". Is it valid for intuitionists as well? For me, it seems a little weird because we are in metamathematics but we still use the law of excluded middle for a potentially infinite number of objects. What is the current stance for this of modern logicians?

Answer (score 3):

Unless provability in the formal system $T$ is decidable, intuitionists would not accept the general assertion "For all formulas $A$, either $A$ is provable in $T$ or it is not."  For one specific $A$, the assertion "Either $A$ is provable in $T$ or it is not" might be intuitionistically acceptable; it depends on the details of $A$ and $T$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am going through one of the Godel's theorem proofs and there the following intuitive predicate is used: $A(a,b):$ $a$ is the Godel's number of formula and $b$ is Godel's number of a proof of the formula. Would that be intuitionistically accepted if $A(a,b)$ is primitive recursive, which means Turing computable?

Comment: As far as I can see, "provable in $T$ or unprovable in $T$" is intuitionistically correct for primitive recursive predicates, as long as the formal system $T$ includes enough arithmetic; Peano Arithmetic would be more than enough.